# Direct access of inner view breaking multiple views per tab behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a tab named Video with multiple views. View1 is the homepage of the tab, from View1 I can access View2 and from View2 I can access View3.

When I am on View3, if I tap the tab icon again I go back to View1 which is good.

However, when I am on another tab and I tap a link which goes directly to View2, when I navigate to View3 and I tap the Video tab icon again I go back to View2 instead of View1.

Is it a normal behavior or am I doing something wrong?
Maybe tabs are supposed to be accessed from their first view and not directly to inner views?

I tried to overwrite the behavior of the tab using on-click and $location without success.

```
.state('tab.videos', { // View1
    url: '/videos',
    views: {
      'tab-videos': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-videos.html',
        controller: 'VideosCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('tab.video-detail', { // View2
    url: '/video/:videoId',
    views: {
      'tab-video': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/video-detail.html',
        controller: 'VideoDetailCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('tab.question-detail', { // View3
    url: '/question/:pdvId',
    views: {
      'tab-pdv': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/question-detail.html',
        controller: 'QuestionDetailCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this answer:
http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-tabs-auto-navigation/13052/16